# Can i really use a dictionary instead of dynamically assigning a variable?

Tags: python, arrays, variables, dataframe, scope

The aim here is to read in many csv files, each to a separate Pandas dataframe. The third line of the following three lines is wrong before the "=". I have read so many posts about using dictionaries rather than dynamic variables but cannot see how to apply that here. Is there an alternative other than the globals() way which seems to have a lot of argument against it?

```
testlist = ['A', 'B', 'C']
for dfsuffix in testlist:
    'df' + dfsuffix = pandas.read_csv(dfsuffix + '.csv')
```

So, for example, i'm looking for the first iteration to be interpreted as:

```
dfA = pandas.read_csv('A.csv')
```

The dataframes are of different row lengths so i don't think a mutidimensional array or a multi-index dataframe is ideal. Although they have the same columns i do not want to append them.

NB. I should add that i do not know beforehand what the contents of testlist will be other than that they will be a list of dates populated by user input.

Comment: Instead of creating 3 variables, create 1 dictionary that has 3 entries. Simple.

Comment: I don't see a dictionary here

Comment: yes, you can use a dictionary. `df[dfsuffix] = pandas.read_csv(dfsuffix + ".csv")` lets you reference the dataframe with `df["A"]`.

Comment: Thanks @BryanOakley but isn't df["A"] referencing a Series / column within a dataframe rather than separate dataframes?

Comment: use `df_dict = {}`, then in the loop, instead of assigning to the *globals dict*, just assign to the one you've just defined: `df_dict[dfsuffix] = pandas.read_csv(dfsuffix + ".csv")`

Comment: No, `df["A"]` is no different than if you had hard-coded `dfA`. It's just a variable holding a reference to a value.

Comment: @JonB451 eh, more like trust in the power of Python's marvelous built-in hash-map datastructure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dictionary is the preferred solution over messing around with dynamically generating variable names.

Consider this code:

```
df = {}
testlist = ['A', 'B', 'C']
for dfsuffix in testlist:
    df[dfsuffix] = pandas.read_csv(dfsuffix + '.csv')
```

It is no different than this code:

```
df = {
    'A': pandas.read_csv('A.csv'),
    'B': pandas.read_csv('B.csv'),
    'C': pandas.read_csv('C.csv')
}
```

The following two statements are functionally identical:

```
dfA = pandas.read_csv('A.csv')
df["A"] = pandas.read_csv('A.csv')
```

The only difference is that the dictionary is easier to use in a loop. The data that is stored is identical.

Comment: Even a dictionary comprehension: `df = {dfsuffix : pandas.read_csv(dfsuffix + '.csv') for dfsuffix in testlist}`...btw - good to see the great tkinter legend crossing over to pandas!

Comment: @Parfait I'm not "crossing over to pandas" -- this isn't a pandas question, it's just basic python. I've never used pandas.